# Azure DevOps setting up multiple feeds for restoring packages

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Trying to setup a Azure DevOps pipeline and currently Restore packages is failing for my ServiceStack package because the version I need is not in the default nuget.org feed.  The version I want is in a MyGet.org feed.

**How and where do I setup the additional MyGet feed in the dev.azure.com portal for this additional package so Azure DevOps can restore it?**

https://www.myget.org/F/servicestack

```
     NuGet Config files used:
         D:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_1.config

     Feeds used:
         https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

     Installed:
         78 package(s) to D:\a\1\s\SomeApi\SomeApi.csproj
   Done executing task "RestoreTask" -- FAILED.
 1>Done building target "Restore" in project "SomeApi.csproj" -- FAILED.
 1>Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\SomeApi\SomeApi.csproj" (Restore target(s)) -- FAILED.
```

Build FAILED.

```
   "D:\a\1\s\SomeApi\SomeApi.csproj" (Restore target) (1) ->
   (Restore target) -> 
     D:\a\1\s\SomeApi\SomeApi.csproj : error NU1102: Unable to find package ServiceStack with version (>= 5.4.1)## Heading ##
   D:\a\1\s\SomeApi\SomeApi.csproj : error NU1102:   - Found 181 version(s) in nuget.org [ Nearest version: 5.4.0 ]

0 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)
```

Answer (score 3):

> Azure DevOps setting up multiple feeds for restoring packages

You could right click your solution on the Solution Explorer, then add a `nuget.config` file with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="MyGetCustomFeed" value="https://dotnet.myget.org/xxx/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>

  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <MyGetCustomFeed>
      <add key="Username" value="xxx" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="xxxx" />
    </MyGetCustomFeed>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

Then submit this file to your repos, and in the nuget restore task select this file:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: For some odd reason while my nuget.config was in the same folder as the solution file, did not appear to be picking up feeds.  However, specifying Feeds in my NuGet.config and setting the path just to NuGet.Config without any folder name solved it for me.  Thanks.

Comment: @richardb, Yes, when you use the nuget.config file in the nuget restore, you need to specify the path for it, otherwise, nuget restore will search the default nuget.config in the default path `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\nuget.config`. Besides, if above answer resolved your question, you can accept it as answer, so that we could archive it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Where ever you're running `nuget restore` should reference a local copy of [NuGet.config](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/redis-geo/blob/master/src/NuGet.Config). Example [restore using a custom NuGet.config in Docker](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/redis-geo/blob/81e4af4ce443fc1b414d929d551d23090fdb9f2c/Dockerfile#L5):

```
$ RUN dotnet restore --configfile ../NuGet.Config
```

Alternatively if the `NuGet.Config` is next to your `.sln` it should automatically be used.

Comment: Thanks - your answer and Leo helped here - had to specify the Path to Nuget.config as did not appear to be finding it automatically despite fact was in same folder as solution file.